# Installation freezes

Tags: usb, freeze

I have a acer swift 314-41 with windows 10 and I wanted to install ubuntu on dualboot. I downloaded both ubuntu 20 and 18 latest releases from the official site, then mounted them on a usb stick with both rufus and balenaEtcher, but the installation keeps freezing on the loading screen with the dots(18) or with the logo ciclying after the filecheck for v20. I have left it running for 30 mins but it just freezes. I have tried changing some boot settings, reading also other questions on this site, but nothing worked. I have secure boot disabled, fast boot too, sata mode on ahci, I tried adding nomedeset, but it has been 3 days and nothing worked.

Last year I installed ubuntu 18.04 on another computer, working on the iso on this swift pc and using the very same usb stick, and everything went smooth.
Does anyone know how to solve the problem? It would really made my day. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you put both on the same USB at the same time with 2 different programs to do so? If you did this why?

Comment: No, I mounted them separately each time of course. I tried both hoping at least one would work.
To add something: they suggested me to press esc during the loading screen to read what is happening and I tried it while installing ubuntu 20.04 (I forgot to mention previously that the file check is fine, no errors are found). The last rows in output are:

Comment: (Part 2)The last rows in output are:
A connection to the bus can't be made
Using CD_ROM mount point /cdrom/
.... it identifies the iso...
Reading Package Indexes...Done
Writing new source list
Source list entries for this disc are:
deb cdrom: Ubuntu 20.04.02 etc...
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set.

Comment: As i found a solution, I will leave it here. In the kernel, you have to pass as boot parameter (after quiet splash ---) "idle=nomwait nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500"

Comment: Maybe use the answer your own question button and put that in there.

Answer (score 0):

As i found a solution, I will leave it here. In the kernel, you have to pass as boot parameter (after quiet splash ---) "idle=nomwait nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500"